# Default pagination in Home/Front page

Tags: pagination, navigation, paginate-links

I am using my home page to show all my posts. Therefore I use `WP_Query`.

When I click on the pagination, the url changes but not the page content.

This is my code,

```
<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'page' => $paged );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="home-post">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div class="thumb-img">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="thumb-hover"></div>
            </div>
            <!--/ thumb image -->
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
            </div>
            <!--/ post excerpt -->
            <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue Reading</a>
        </div>
        <!--/ home post -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="home-pagination">
        <!-- then the pagination links -->
        <?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
        <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Change `'page'` to `'paged'` in the query arguments.

Comment: You should not be running custom queries in place of the main query on the home page any type of archive page. It will always cause headaches with pagination

Comment: @PieterGoosen then what is the better way to do this. I need to show all posts in my home page. Show 10 posts at a time and for other posts I need to use pagination

Comment: Simply use the [default loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: Also, never ever use `$wp_query` as a local variable, this breaks the main query object which in turn breaks many many other functions

Comment: @PieterGoosen so how can I create argument list and exclude $wp_query the way you have suggested me.

Answer (score -1):

try this for get_query_var

```
<?php  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ); ?>
```

For more information check this url

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: Why is the syntax wrong, `page` is a valid value as well. Also, you do not need to pass the second parameter